# How to solve msdb dbo sp send dbmail File attachement in SQL windows server

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

i need to attach remote desktop files via connect msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

I get an error as in SQL server as below

**Attachment file \example.com\E$\Attachments\test.txt is invalid.**

However if i type this in RUN command it opens the file correctly, if I set a local file path it works fine with no errors.

What can be the root cause of this issue ?

below is my SQL query.

```
SET @v_recipients = 'email@example.com'
                SET  @v_copy_recipients = 'email2@example3.com'
                    SET @v_body =  'test mail'
                    SET @v_subject =  'Test mail'
                    SET @v_email_template_id = 1
                SET  @v_queue_id = 1
                    SET @v_attachments = N'\\example.com\E$\Attachments\test.txt'           

set @p_database_profile_name='profile_name'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @recipients = @v_recipients,
                @copy_recipients = @v_copy_recipients,
                @body = @v_body, 
                @subject = @v_subject,
                @file_attachments= @v_attachments,

                @profile_name = @p_database_profile_name,
                @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Comment: what is example.com?

Answer (score 2):

Attachments are subject of certain limitations with regards to security context (OS vs SQL server) - probably the remarks section of the  **[sp_send_dbmail documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)**  might give you a clue:

> ... Database Mail uses the Microsoft Windows security context of the current user to control access to files. Therefore, users who are authenticated with SQL Server Authentication cannot attach files using @file_attachments. Windows does not allow SQL Server to provide credentials from a remote computer to another remote computer. Therefore, Database Mail may not be able to attach files from a network share in cases where the command is run from a computer other than the computer that SQL Server runs on ...

Comment: So, is there any acceptable hack to get around this?